# what happens if an angular js promise is not rejected and it fails?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am maintaining old code and I happened upon this code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.post(url,{"username": username},{cache: true})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(config);
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

return deferred.promise;
```

I am curious what happens if this http request is  in error.
Those this mean deferred.reject is never called?
Should I update this to have an error function?:

```
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
            console.log(data);
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This falls upon the **[Deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)** category. Since all **[`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)** methods returns a promise by itself, then all you have to do is return it, don't create another deferred object. When a request fails, the function itself returns the rejected promise.

Example

```
function saveSomething(url, username) {
  return $http.post(url,{"username": username},{cache: true});
}

// usage
saveSomething('http://whatever', 'myUserName')
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```